# Oracle APEX 5.0: Charts not displaying properly

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, anychart

I'm using the D3 Line Chart plugin to create charts in my application. When I create one chart, it works fine but when I add a second chart the second chart doesn't appear and the legend from the second chart appears in the first chart too. Not sure why the 2nd chart is getting merged into the first one.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out they both have the same Static ID which caused this issue.